# Turn a list into a list which each item has multiplicity 1

Tags: python, frequency

Suppose we have a list, where every item has its frequency: 1, 2, 3 , etc. Then, 
from this list, I would like to get another list where every item has a frequency 1.

For example, the original list is:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5]
```

The idea is to get another list such as:

```
B = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

How can I do it?

This is what I implemented in Python:

```
for i in range(10):
    k = i
    item1 = A[k]
    for j in range(k):
        l = j
        item2 = A[l]
        if (item1 != item2):
            B.append(item1)
            break
```

But I get:

```
B = [1, 2, 5]
```

Can someone  please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So erase all duplicates starting to erase from the right?

Comment: just use `list(set(A))`

Comment: This question is a repeat, as posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a built-in function for this but I would rather do this:

```
def Remove(duplicate): 
    final_list = [] # make an empty list
    for num in duplicate: # iterate over the given list
        if num not in final_list: # if number is not in the list, push it to the list.
            final_list.append(num) 
    return final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) in order to remove duplicates and preserve order:

```
from  more_itertools import unique_everseen

A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5]
B = list(unique_everseen(items))
print(B)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

If you don't have `more_itertools` installed on your machine, you can install it using [`PyPi`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):

```
pip install more-itertools
```

Answer (score 0):

A good method for this is to use the 'set' data structure.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5]
a_prime=list(set(a))
print (a_prime)
Out:
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```